# MySQL: how to insert multiple entries but skip the existing ones?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I am trying to insert multiple entries into a table. However, some of these entries may be the same to existing ones: in such scenarios, these duplicate entries should not be inserted.

Here's an example:

table

```
id  name    number
1   alice   12345
2   bob     67890
```

id is auto-increment, while name and number are actual data.

Say now I have 3 more entries that I want to insert in the table using one instruction:

```
name    number
alice   12345
alice   54321
bob     67890
```

Since the 1st and 3rd record is already there in the table, it would be desired to ignore them in insertion. But the db will take id as a key also, which is always different for each entries. So how may I subvert this, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the unique key is supposed to be (name, number), then put a unique index on it.  If you want to skip duplicate entries, check out INSERT...IGNORE or do some serious magic with ON DUPLICATE KEY.